# Squid Proxy Configuration for Inbound request from the Internet

Tags: squid

I like to configure a squid proxy server which allows users from the Internet to annonymously connect and then be able to go to other web sites through the proxy. Anyone have a sample configuraiton I can use? The environment is squid 3 on Debian Linux.

Comment: If you want to get your Internet connection shut down, at least do some dissidents a favour and install Tor as an exit node.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from a FreeBSD environment but it's very similar.  It's set to listen on 10.0.0.4:8083.  However, I would strongly recommend NOT having an open proxy.  Unless you're very, very careful and have some form of access control in place you're setting yourself up for trouble.  People will launch attacks through your servers, commit fraud through them, etc, etc.

```
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny to_localhost

http_access allow all
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED all
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED passwords
icp_access deny all
http_port 10.0.0.4:8083
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
access_log /usr/local/squid/logs/access.log squid
useragent_log /usr/local/squid/logs/useragent.log squid
debug_options ALL,7
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
acl shoutcast rep_header X-HTTP09-First-Line ^ICY.[0-9]
upgrade_http0.9 deny shoutcast
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache
```